# While loop only show elements x number of times

Tags: php

I've got this expanding/closing div. Where I would have a category title (to show once) , and underneath have the sub-category information (need to loop through x amount of times). Everything (sort of) works except I need the sub-category information to loop through the amount of times it exists.

For now This is the result I get so far: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fabw.jpg

As you can see it's closing the tag, looping through again and adding the subcategory underneath

```
$result_array = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM tbl_customer, categories WHERE tbl_customer.category_QA = categories.id ORDER BY Category ASC");
    $checkCategory = '';

    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result_array)){


   //works as it shows the category once
       if  ($checkCategory != $data["Category"]){


    echo'           
    <div class="collapse-group">
              <div class="collapse-item">
                <div class="collapse-head">
                      '.$data["Category"].'
                </div>
                <div class="collapse-content">';


      }


    //Here is where I need to loop through all sub category data and display them 
     echo '    <p>  '.$data["productName"].'</p>';



      //Should only run once all sub category data has been displayed 
      //close all tags 
      if  ($checkCategory != $data["Category"]){

    echo    '
                      </div>
                 </div>
              </div>';

        $checkCategory = $data["Category"];


      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write properly your tags, instead of

```
'            <
            div class = "collapse-group" >
```

you need

```
'<div class = "collapse-group">
```

and instead of

```
' <
            /div>
```

you need

```
' </div>
```

This should fix the error, but I will also propose a better approach for you. First of all, you need to make sure this is reusable, so let's make sure it's inside a `function`. Secondly, you need to make sure that the code generation is separated from the display:

```
function generateCategories($result_array) {
    $checkCategory = '';
    $output = array();
    $index = -1;
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result_array)) {
        if ($checkCategory != $data["Category"]) {
            $checkCategory = $data["Category"];
            $output[]=array("key" => $checkCategory, "values" => array());
            $index++;
        }
        $output[$index]["values"][]=$data["productName"];
    }
    return $output;
}

function generateCategoryStructure($input) {
    $output = "";
    for ($index = 0; $index < count($input); $index++) {
        $output .= '<div class = "collapse-group">'.
                       '<div class = "collapse-item">'.
                           '<div class = "collapse-head">'.$input[$index]["key"].'</div>'.
                           '<div class = "collapse-content">';
        for ($innerIndex = 0; $innerIndex < count($input[$index]["values"]); $innerIndex++) {
            $output .=         '<p>'.$input[$index]["values"][$innerIndex].'</p>';
        }
        $output .=         '</div>'.
                       '</div>'.
                   '</div>';
    }
}
```

and then:

```
echo generateCategoryStructure(generateCategories($result_array));
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I understand I need to write my tags properly, although how would that be a fix? The while loop currently allows me to show the category title once, but then I need something to tell me when its finished looping through all     `echo '  <p>  '.$data["productName"]. '</p>';` so then afterwards I can run the last if statement to close all the tags.

The code you provided (which im very grateful for) seems to give - Undefined offset: 2

and -  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Comment: @jimmy If your tags are not properly opened/closed, then you will have an HTML generated with unexpected behaviors. If you have something like <    /div> then the div is not properly closed. You need to make sure that the tags you generate are proper. If you still have a problem afterwards, then it will be much easier to detect and fix it. As about my code, I would like to kindly ask you to edit your question and add the exact code you were trying to work with and the line where you have the error.

Comment: Fixed closing tags. Same problem, but probably my fault for not explaining it well enough. Essentially, the first if statement works as it only show the category title once, the second part `echo ' <p> '.$data["productName"]. '</p>';` needs to loop through until all sub-category information has been shown - then only run the last if statement, since that is used to close the tags  (from the first if). It doesn't work, as the last if statement is running, pretty much after  `echo ' <p> '.$data["productName"]. '</p>';` so you end up getting that weird affect.

Comment: @jimmy the condition of ($checkCategory != $data["Category"]) is the very same at the start and at the end of the code block of the cycle. The only way that could have a true evaluation at the start and a false at the end as you explained is if either $checkCategory or $data["Category"] has changed between the two, but that does not happen in your code. $data["Category"] can only be changed at the start of the code block as the next record becomes the current record, and $checkCategory can only change at the end of the loop.

Comment: @jimmy another question: is it possible that $data["Category"] or $data["productName"] contains some value which could be interpreted as HTML code? Also, I would like to kindly ask you to try my code again and explain how did you try it in your project and which (for) cycle line has thrown the error for you?

Comment: @jimmy found a typo in my code which must be the cause of the error you experienced. I have edited my answer. Can you test it now?

Comment: There's only a few entries in the DB and none of them could be interpreted as code.  I've tried your code again, no errors this time, but nothings showing on the page, checked the dev tools, cant find any `<div class="collapse-group">` tags or anything like that

Comment: @jimmy you are either not calling the functions, not properly calling them or not properly echoing them. To know which the exact issue is you will need to edit your question and share with us with the current version of the code.